# I am trying to make a dot placement on an image, but whenever the screen is resized the dot placement changes its location

Tags: javascript, html, css

The point is pointing on the phones camera, but whenever the screen is resized the position of the dot changes. I want to make sure that whenever the screen is resized the dot isn't going all over the place, instead it remains pointing on the phone's camera. Does anyone have any clue what I am doing wrong here?

CSS code

```
.spec::before { /* TO MODIFY THE SPECS WRITINGS OF THE HEADER PHOTOS */
    content: '';
    background: var(--secondary);
    width: 6em;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2.2em;
    left: 50%;
}

.phone .spec::before {
    transform:
        translateX(-145%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.tablet .spec::before {
    transform:
        translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.dot {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -5em;
    height: 1.8em;
    width: 1.8em;
    border: 1px var(--primary) solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: expand 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.phone .dot {left: -30%;} 
.phone .dot {bottom: -240%;}/* change the dot placement */
.tablet .dot {left: 65%;}

.dot::before, .pagination a::before {
    content: '';
    background: var(--accent);
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (attach HTML as a code snippet).